# Can I use Linodes DNS manager without running a Linode?

Tags: server, mail-server, linode, mx-record

Can I use Linodes DNS manager without running a Linode? I want to remove all of my Linodes, but use the DNS manager to point the MX Records to a different place (so the mail still continues to work). Is this possible, or will removing the Linode stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to keep at least one active Linode on the account for Linode's DNS hosting to remain in service. You will need to find a new DNS hosting provider if you would like to remove all of your Linodes.